# Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am facing an issue where i am reading images saved on firebase storage and putting them in a pdf

```
  List<Uint8List> images = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < currentOrder.imageNames.length; i++) {
    await storageRef
        .child(
            'Orders/${currentOrder.orderId}/${currentOrder.imageNames.elementAt(i)}')
        .getData()
        .then((value) => {
              images.add(value!),
            });
  }
```

i receive the following error

```
Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://firebasestorage.googleapis...
```

When i click the link it downloads the image - so everything is right
But there is a configuration in GCP where i add cors.json to my project
having the following:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
  ]
```

Then run this on gcp terminal

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<bucket-name>
```

but i get this error

> Setting CORS on gs://
> ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.update access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.update' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

Note that i am able to write to firebase storage successfully but not reading it

i tried

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth application-default login
```

then rerun the cors set cmd but it isn't working

Also note that i have another project on gcp where i can read from bucket and download files etc. (i did that project 1 year ago)

But now this new project it is not working whatever i do

Update 10Nov2023

.
.
.
.

I also tried the following in GCP but to no avail - Creating a new role with storage.buckets. permissions

ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.update access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.update' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

1 - Login to GCP 2 - Go to IAM and Admin -> Role -> Create Role -> Fill in the info -> Add Permissions Filter by Service: firebasestorage Check all the Permissions

Most importantly add 'storage.buckets.update'

3 - Now go to IAM and Admin -> Service Accounts -> Create Service Account -> Fill in fields -> Create and Continute -> Role -> Custom -> Select the created role -> Continue -> Done

4 - Now the new Service Account shows -> Click on the menu Button -> Manage Keys -> Add Key -> JSON The Json is downloaded

5 - Open the terminal -> Open Editor -> Upload the JSON to the directory of the cors.json

6 - run the following command: gcloud auth [serviceaccountname]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=[jsonfilename].json

excluding the brackets []

7 - then run the second command:

gsutil cors set cors.json gs://xxxx.appspot.com

I even added this role to all the service accounts available but still got the same error

...

I also tried generating new OAuth Keys as suggested here but the error persists

[image: 401-error-code-documentation]